# Do you use css reset in your child theme

Tags: css, reset

I am trying to make a child theme . I want to use the html5 reset from this website . http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/  Anyone here use the code ?

Can you find me a child theme with lots of functions and codes. I've downloaded and doing research . I think i need to know more. Please give me a standard child theme(if you want to) I've to explore more.

Waiting for your answer . Happy New Year . Thanks .

Comment: Sorry, theme recommendations are [off topic](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1217/73) here.

Answer (score 2):

The [_s](http://underscores.me) (or Underscores) theme is a great starter theme. It's not a child theme, rather a barebones template that you can build on. It includes many features such as HTML5 templates, custom header, custom background and theme options implementations, custom template tags, 5 sample CSS layouts, starter non-presentational CSS that you can build on, and lots more. You can learn more about it, and create your own Underscores-based theme on its website, [Underscores.me](http://underscores.me)

Comment: You can edit the `style.css` file and replace the already present CSS reset with the HTML5 Doctor one

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to make a child theme . I want to use the html5 reset from
>   this website . Anyone here use the code ?

The whole point of a stylesheet, in my humble opinion, is avoiding that sort of preliminary low-level work. In theory, the parent theme should create the basic foundation, leaving the child theme to deal exclusively with matters directly relating to the end-user experience.

> Can you find me a child theme with lots of functions and codes. I've
>   downloaded and doing research. I think i need to know more. Please
>   give me a standard child theme(if you want to) I've to explore more.

I would recommend that you start with a blank child theme, rather than adapting somebody else's. The [Graphene](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/graphene) theme is a personal favorite of mine to build child themes on because it starts out looking pretty sharp and it includes a smorgasbord of *hooks* which allow your child theme to adapt it to your liking.

To get started, install the Graphene theme, then follow the clear and easy WordPress Codex article on [Child Themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).